# Collapse empurrando as Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, collapse

Criei um collapse porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer com que ele empurre as Divs para baixo, assim ficando sobreposto ao conteúdo.

Tentei alguns códigos no CSS mas não estão dando resultado.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="collapsible-menu">
 <button type="button" class="collapsible"><img src="/img/header/earth-grid-symbol.png" alt="Menu Linguagem"></button>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="img/header/earth.png">
    <img src="img/header/br.png">
   </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

**CSS:**

```
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border: 2px solid #f0db00;
    }

    button.collapsible {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .content{
        border: 2px solid #f0db00;
        margin-left: -250px;
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
```

Comment: monte um exemplo verificável que mostre o problema, só olhado o código fica difícil de entender

Comment: No teste ele funciona. Porém se vc olhar na página de teste ele não dá espaço na div.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/renanranzani/a6dkcpu0/21/ -Teste
http://www.siteesquadros.kinghost.net/ - Página

Comment: tente por o exemplo aqui no site, tem suporte a scripts do jeito que o jsfiddle faz

Answer (score 0):

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div#collapsible-menu{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border: 2px solid #f0db00;
    }

    button.collapsible {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .content{
        border: 2px solid #f0db00;
        margin-left: -250px;
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    
    div.banner-up{
        /*border: 4px solid #000045;*/
        height: 150px;
        width: 100%;

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        line-height: 150px;

        background-color: #000045 ;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #f0db00;
    }

    div.banner-up h1{
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
 
                                <div id="collapsible-menu">
                                <button type="button" class="collapsible"><img src="/img/header/earth-grid-symbol.png" alt="Menu Linguagem"></button>
                                    <div class="content">
                                     <img src="img/header/br.png" alt="Lingua Portuguesa">
                                     <img src="img/header/earth.png" alt="Linguas Internacionais - Inglês e Espanhol">
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

      <div class="banner-up">
            <h1>Perfiladeira de Telhas</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
            <div class="container-img">
                <img src="img/perfiladeira-de-telhas/perfiladeiras-de-telhas-metalicas.png" alt="Perfiladeira de Telha Metálica">
            </div>
```